# Iteration of two list in loop with if else statement (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two list(oil_price and price, both the same length) and want it to iterate through both loops and go through the if-else statements. The code only goes does the first row. Can anyone help?

```
for x in oil_price:
        for y in price:
            if float(x) <= 60:
                cost = y * qty
                if cost > funds:
                    return funds, stocks
                else:
                    cash_balance = float(funds - cost)
                    stocks += qty
                    return cash_balance, stocks

            elif float(x) > 60:
                sale = qty * y
                if qty > stocks:
                    return funds, stocks
                else:
                    cash_balance = float(funds + sale)
                    stocks_owned = stocks - qty
                    return cash_balance, stocks_owned
```

Comment: What would be your expected output?

Comment: Since you use `return` within the loop, your function returns on the first iteration and never goes further.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Błotosmętek's answer (use of a `return` statement exits the function after the first iteration of the loop) , you could use a list of lists (2D-list/array, if you will) to store the intermediate results, then use `continue` to go to the next step of the loop. This way, you calculate the results for all combinations of `oil_price` and `price`.

So, it could look something like this:

```
results = []

for x in oil_price:
    for y in price:
        if float(x) <= 60:
            cost = y * qty
            if cost > funds:
                results.append([funds, stocks])
                continue
            else:
                cash_balance = float(funds - cost)
                stocks += qty
                results.append([cash_balance, stocks])
                continue
        elif float(x) > 60:
            sale = qty * y
            if qty > stocks:
                results.append([funds, stocks])
                continue
            else:
                cash_balance = float(funds + sale)
                stocks_owned = stocks - qty
                results.append([cash_balance, stocks_owned])
                continue
```

I'm sure this could look a lot prettier, but it should work nonetheless.